# Add each element of a string on a new line in ArrayList

Tags: android, json, string, arraylist, android-spinner

I have a `String`, an `ArrayList<String>` and a `Spinner`.

In my code, I add `String` elements in my `ArrayList` and then in my `Spinner`. All good, except the fact that everything is on a single line, and I want each of the elements ("one,two,three,four") in a new line.

The main problem is that I do not know what does the `String` object contains, but I managed to separate the words in the `String`.

So...How can I break the line after each word in my string and then add it on a new line in my spinner?

Note: I do not know what String `accounts` contains or how many values it has in it. I receive the string from a post method.

```
JSONArray userAcounts = objects.getJSONArray("Accounts");

for (int i = 0;i < userAcounts.length();i++){
    JSONObject myStreamingAcounts = userAcounts.getJSONObject(i);
    accountType += myStreamingAcounts.getString("Type");
}
ArrayList<String> spinnerAccounts = new ArrayList<>();

Spinner accounts = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.accounts);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerAccounts);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
accounts.setAdapter(adapter);
spinnerAccounts.add(System.lineSeparator());
spinnerAccounts.add(accountID.toString());
```

Comment: I posted an answer, but now when I read your question again I'm confused about what you really mean... Where are the words you want to add to the Spinner? Are they in `accountID.toString()` or in `userAccounts`?

Comment: Can you give sample of JSONArray that you might receive

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm mistaken, but does your `accountID.toString()` contain the words? If so, you can do something like this:

```
    String[] words = accountID.toString().split(" ");
    for( String word : words ){
        spinnerAccounts.add(word)
    }
```

I'm assuming here that the words are separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

1. Get the Spinner and set the adapter
2. Loop over you JSON array
3. Get the String values out of the JSON Objects and add to adapter

```
Spinner accounts = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.accounts);

ArrayList<String> spinnerAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerAccounts);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
accounts.setAdapter(adapter);

JSONArray userAcounts = objects.getJSONArray("Accounts");
for (int i = 0; i < userAcounts.length(); i++){
    JSONObject myStreamingAcounts = userAcounts.getJSONObject(i);
    adapter.add(myStreamingAcounts.getString("Type"));
}

// Not sure why you needed these...
// adapter.add(System.lineSeparator());
// adapter.add(accountID.toString());
```